# Pipe large files takes a lot of memory

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I have a program which reads a large file from a stream and writes it to a file.

Here's reading the file from stream

```
var stream = new Stream.PassThrough();

Request(options, function (error, res, body) {
    if (error) {
         Logger.error('ProxyManager', 'getStream', error);
         return callback(error);
      }
}).pipe(stream); // first pipe call
```

Here's writing the file

```
var outputFile = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
stream.pipe(outputFile); // second pipe call
```

My problem is the process takes a lot of memory when transferring a large file which seems like pipe is keeping the whole file in the memory in the first pipe or the second call. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You have a callback and it has `body` parameter which is the whole file. Omit callback and use `error` event instead.

Comment: Yep. exactly that. It buffers the response it seems. I changed it to a normal https call and works good now. Thanks.